# É possível usar PHP num campo data-title?

Tags: php, html, mysql

É possível usar PHP dentro de um campo `data-title`?

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div id="grid" class="m-row shuffle--container shuffle--fluid">
      <?
      $result = $connection -> query("SELECT * FROM portfolio") or die($connection -> error);
      while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      ?>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 m-col-md-3 picture-item" 
               data-groups='["<?=$row['portfolio_tipo']?>"]' 
               data-date-created="<?=$row['portfolio_data']?>" 
               data-title="<?=$row['portfolio_titulo']?>">
          <div class="picture-item__inner">
```

O problema é que todos os campo `data-...` não funciona com php lá dentro. Nenhum dos atributos funciona.

Este código em html estava a funcionar perfeitamente, depois de colocar com php deixou de funcionar.

Comment: Não funcionam em que sentido? Não mostram os valores? Pois a situação que você propôs não vejo nenhum problema em ser executada. Certifique-se de utilizar php > 5.4, pois o <?= (simplificação do echo) , acredito que é só dessa versão para cima, caso eu não esteja enganado.

Comment: Complementando a informação sobre a short tag: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php

Comment: basta adicionar um `echo` antes da variável que "segura" o valor que você deseja imprimir

Comment: Testei localmente aqui e no Ideone com um array qualquer https://ideone.com/nINakE ... funcionou corretamente. Tem certeza que os dados não estão vazios?

Comment: Sim tenho a certeza que não estão vazias, estou a usar as mesmas variáveis noutro sitio e funciona, só esses atributos não estão a funcionar

Comment: @MárcioAndré  Você está com a configuração `short_open_tag` ativada para poder usar `<?=` ?

Comment: sim uso sempre assim

Answer (score 2):

O php funciona em qualquer parte do arquivo. Como você relatou o problema citando apenas o atributo `data-title` acredito que os outros atributos (`data-date-created`, ...) estejam funcionando. Se for isso mesmo, acredito que a sua variável `$row['portfolio_titulo']` esteja vazia ou não exista.

---

**Edit:** você pode ter alguns problemas com aspas. Por exemplo, se tentar colocar uma string `Meu título com "aspas"` no atributo `data-title` ficaria assim:

```
data-title="Meu título com "aspas""
```

Para contornar este problema, você pode utilizar a função [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlspecialchars.php) ou [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php):

```
data-title="<?= htmlentities($row['portfolio_titulo']) ?>"
```

Comment: O problema está em todos os atributos.

Comment: Execute um `var_dump` na variável `$row` em algum lugar da página em que você possa ver o resultado e verificar se a variável está correta e contém mesmo os valores que você está tentando utilizar. `var_dump($row);`

Comment: Sim as variáveis têm conteúdo, estou a usa-las noutros sítios e elas funcionam.

Comment: Mesmo que funcione em outro lugar, é interessante procurar o erro em qualquer lugar possível no script **atual**. Quando você menos espera, algo pequeno ao qual você não dá valor pode representar o problema que você está procurando.

Comment: Concordo plenamente @Oesli, mas não é de variáveis vazias, inspeccionei elemento e elas encontram-se cheias

Answer (score 1):

**1** - Verifique se seu documento é `.php`

**2** - Você não precisa por **colchetes** `data-groups='["<?=$row['portfolio_tipo']?>"]'`

```
...

    <?php
          $portfolio_tipo = $row['portfolio_tipo'];
          $portfolio_data = $row['portfolio_data'];
          $portfolio_titulo = $row['portfolio_titulo'];

    ?>


          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 m-col-md-3 picture-item" 
                   data-groups="<?=$portfolio_tipo?>" 
                   data-date-created="<?=$portfolio_data?>" 
                   data-title="<?=$portfolio_titulo?>">
          <div class="picture-item__inner">

...
```

**3 -** Faça um teste antes de selecionar os valores com a query:

```
...

    <?php
          $portfolio_tipo = 'teste tipo';
          $portfolio_data = 'teste data';
          $portfolio_titulo = 'teste titulo';

    ?>


          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 m-col-md-3 picture-item" 
                   data-groups="<?=$portfolio_tipo?>" 
                   data-date-created="<?=$portfolio_data?>" 
                   data-title="<?=$portfolio_titulo?>">
          <div class="picture-item__inner">

...
```

Comment: Que diferença faz esse código daquele que eu tenho?

Comment: Retire os colchetes.

Comment: E faça com essa organização.

Comment: já testei, não funcionou

Comment: Agora faça assim: $portfolio_tipo = "valore teste"; E TESTE! SE VIER ALGO, SEU SELECT NÃO PRESTA!

Comment: não funciona a mesma, só deixou de funcionar depois de eu colocar o php, quando estava só em html funcionava 100%

Comment: Meu caro, era pra está funcionando. Tem certeza que o seu documento é `.php` ??

Comment: Sim tenho a certeza que é um ficheiro `.php`. Obviamente era para estar a funcionar e por não estar a solucionar o problema vim aqui para tentar procurar ajuda.

Comment: "Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available." O seu php é superior a 5.4?

Comment: Sim, não tenho problemas em usar isso. @Lollipop assim como você disse funciona, mas quando uso com query deixa de funcionar

Comment: A questão é.... SEU SELECT traz algum resultado? 
Se sua consulta não trouxer nada, não vai aparecer nada ali, logicamente

Answer (score -3):

Sim, é possível! Inclusive creio que essa foi a intenção inicial ao se criar esses atributos no `HTML5`. Criar um ambiente mais agradável ao usuário sem ter que se fazer diversas consultas ao banco... na primeira consulta já popular todos dados necessários do servidor nos campos `data` e deixar o resto em cargo do browser do usuário utilizando o `front-end` e tirando a responsabilidade do servidor de criar toda a dinâmica da página.

Tente fazer isso:
Fiz um teste aqui e funcionou normalmente os atributos `data`

```
<div id="grid" class="m-row shuffle--container shuffle--fluid">
  <?
$result = $connection -> query("SELECT * FROM portfolio") or die($connection -> error);
while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    echo  '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 m-col-md-3 picture-item" 
        data-groups="['.$row['portfolio_tipo'].']" 
        data-date-created='.$row['portfolio_data'].' 
        data-title='.$row['portfolio_titulo'].'>'; ?>

      <div class="picture-item__inner">
```

Se mesmo assim continua não funcionando, verifique se sua consulta no banco traz algum resultado....

Comment: `<?=` já é um `echo`. Usar os dois em conjunto gerará um erro.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro fiz um teste aqui e funcionou normalmente, editei a resposta pra ficar mais dinâmico...

Answer (score -4):

No PHP, quando não se dá um `ECHO` nas variáveis, ele não imprime o valor da mesma na página transformando ela em HTML. seu erro está nisso. tente colocar o ECHO que resolve.

Comment: `<?=` já é um `echo`.

Comment: não conheço `<?=`como um `ECHO`, tanto porque isso não é nem identificado como uma abertura de tag PHP. o correto é você fazer o `<?php echo $row['portfolio_tipo']; ?>`.

Comment: @LeandroLUK http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: no mesmo link que você me mandou @RafaelWithoeft tem a informação `Note: Because this is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using variable functions` creio que seja por isso que não esteja funcionando, portanto é melhor fazer com o echo mesmo.

Comment: @LeandroLUK Só quis demonstrar o uso da short tag, no caso `<?php echo $variavel ?>` funcionaria do mesmo jeito que `<?= $variavel ?>`, espero que não tenha interpretado errado o meu comentário, não quis julgar o certo ou errado, só demonstrar os dois lados... o conceito de `variable functions`, pode ser visto aqui: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php